# Convert time from Arabic To English in PHP

Tags: php

I would like to change the Arabic number to English using php, the numbers also has some string.

Here is what I need to change: (abc١٢:١٢:٠٠abc١٢٣) to (abc12:12:00abc123).

I tried this function:

```
function convert($string) {
    $arabic = array('۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '٤', '۵', '٦', '۷', '۸', '۹');
    $num = range(0, 9);
    return str_replace($arabic, $num, $string);
}
```

The above code changes the last 3 numbers but it does not change the numbers between the colon.

please help me.

Comment: This code works perfectly for me

Comment: See http://3v4l.org/GhTk9